# Convert Regex to be safari compliant

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I am using the following code to find any instances of "\n" newline that doesn't have a space on both sides and add a space on both sides.

**Scenarios**

> 1. There is a space on both sides of /n. = Do Nothing
> 2. There is a space either before or after the /n = Add a space on both sides.
> 3. There are no spaces on either side = Add a space on both sides.

**But why do you need this?**

I need to space seperate words in a paragraph without affecting the paragraph structure. If I split by /s then the structure is gone, so in order to maintain it I want to put a space on either side of the /n new line.

**This looks ok, whats the problem?**

This works for new version of Chrome, but doesn't work for old version and doesn't work for Safari and needs to be support across browsers

**Question:**

How can I maintain this logic without using non Safari supported Regex using Dart.

**Code Example**

```
var regex = RegExp("\n(?! )|(?<! )\n");

if (text.contains(regex)) {
  String newString = text.replaceAll(regex, " \n ");
  updatedString = newString;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to keep your regex functionality as is? `\n(?! )|(?<! )\n` regex will match a newline that is either not followed with a space or a newline that has no space before, and add spaces on *both* ends, this is a wrong pattern, IMHO.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Im open to any suggestions that match the scenarios that I mentioned.  the key thing is how to do without look aheads that Safari doesn't support. I appreciate your help

Comment: I am not sure, what about `RegExp(" ?\n ?")` and keep on using `text.replaceAll(regex, " \n ")`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hmmm.. How would that work? what does that regex do?

Comment: See [demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/QqvLCD/1). Adds single spaces around newline if missing keeping them if they are both there.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That looks like it might work, let me update my code and test it.

Comment: What does a browser has to do with what seems to be pure dart code?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That works great on Safari as well and older version of Chrome and FF. Thanks. Please add it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @Alex.F Flutter Web uses Dart.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```dart
var regex = RegExp(" ?\n ?");
updatedString = text.replaceAll(regex, " \n ");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QqvLCD/1)

The `" ?\n ?"` pattern matches an optional space, then a newline, and then an optional space, and then the match is replaced with a space+newline+space yielding the expected result: if there is are spaces on left and right, they are kept, else, a space is added.